# Simple query executing slowly, how to speed it up?

Tags: postgresql, index-tuning

```
select
    json_agg(distinct (palette_color.id, ciel, ciea, cieb, weight, hex) 
             ORDER BY (palette_color.id, ciel, ciea, cieb, weight, hex) ASC
            ) as colors,
    "palette"."loves"
from (
    select "palette_id"
    from "palette_color"
    where "ciel" between '22.5' and '27.5' 
      and "ciea" between '-5' and '0'
      and "cieb" between '-22.3' and '-17.3' 
    group by "palette_id"
    ) as "palettes"
  left join "palette_color" 
    on "palette_color"."palette_id" = "palettes"."palette_id"
  left join "palette" 
    on "palette"."id" = "palettes"."palette_id"
where 
    "palettes"."palette_id" is not null 
group by 
    "palette"."id", 
    "palette_color"."palette_id" ;
```

This simple query takes 1.1 seconds. The table palette_color 1.5M and palette with 300k rows, so I think it should be much faster (<0.1 second). Can't seem to crack this nut.

**Explain**

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=102616.35..102619.18 rows=126 width=39) (actual time=856.686..865.843 rows=222 loops=1)
  Group Key: palette.id, palette_color.palette_id
  ->  Sort  (cost=102616.35..102616.66 rows=126 width=39) (actual time=856.518..856.558 rows=1105 loops=1)
        Sort Key: palette.id, palette_color.palette_id
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 135kB
        ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=59711.32..102611.95 rows=126 width=39) (actual time=524.110..855.694 rows=1105 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: (palette_color.palette_id = palette_color_1.palette_id)
              ->  Seq Scan on palette_color  (cost=0.00..37366.18 rows=1475518 width=31) (actual time=0.002..161.160 rows=1484522 loops=1)
              ->  Hash  (cost=59711.01..59711.01 rows=25 width=12) (actual time=524.085..524.085 rows=222 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 18kB
                    ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=59499.68..59711.01 rows=25 width=12) (actual time=522.641..524.003 rows=222 loops=1)
                          ->  HashAggregate  (cost=59499.26..59499.51 rows=25 width=4) (actual time=522.610..522.662 rows=222 loops=1)
                                Group Key: palette_color_1.palette_id
                                ->  Seq Scan on palette_color palette_color_1  (cost=0.00..59498.95 rows=122 width=4) (actual time=0.024..522.059 rows=222 loops=1)
                                      Filter: ((palette_id IS NOT NULL) AND (ciel >= '22.5'::real) AND (ciel <= '27.5'::real) AND (ciea >= '-5'::real) AND (ciea <= '0'::real) AND (cieb >= '-22.299999'::real) AND (cieb <= '-17.299999'::real))
                                      Rows Removed by Filter: 1484300
                          ->  Index Scan using palettes_pkey on palette  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.005..0.006 rows=1 loops=222)
                                Index Cond: (id = palette_color_1.palette_id)
```

**Tables**

```
CREATE TABLE public.palette_color
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('palette_color_id_seq'::regclass),
  hex text,
  weight real,
  palette_id integer,
  ciel real,
  ciea real,
  cieb real,
  raw_weight integer,
  CONSTRAINT palette_color_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT palette_color_palette_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (palette_id)
      REFERENCES public.palette (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

CREATE TABLE public.palette
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('palettes_id_seq'::regclass),
  loves integer,
  comments integer,
  num_colors integer,
  link text,
  views integer,
  favorites integer,
  title text,
  CONSTRAINT palettes_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT palette_link_key UNIQUE (link)
)
```

**Edit:** Thanks for the tips. The query is now running at 400 mili. Still seems slow. To clarify, I dont think I can make palette_color.palette_id a pkey because palette and palette_color have a one to many relationship. For example, 5 palette_colors per palette.

```
SELECT
json_agg((palette_color.id, ciel, ciea, cieb, weight, hex)) as colors,
palette.id,
palette.loves,
palette.comments
FROM (
    SELECT palette_id as id
    FROM palette_color
    WHERE ciel BETWEEN '22.5' AND '27.5'
    AND ciea BETWEEN '-5' AND '0'
    AND cieb BETWEEN '-22.3' AND '-17.3'
    GROUP BY palette_id
) AS p
INNER JOIN palette_color
ON palette_color.palette_id = p.id
INNER JOIN palette
ON palette.id = p.id
GROUP BY p.id, palette.id, palette_color.palette_id;
```

Comment: Are there really `palette_color` rows where `palette_id` is NULL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  LEFT OUTER JOIN palette 
    ON palette.id = palettes.palette_id
WHERE 
    palettes.palette_id IS NOT NULL
```

I would put that `WHERE` clause in the original subselect.

```
from (
    select "palette_id"
    from "palette_color"
    WHERE palettes.palette_id IS NOT NULL 
      AND "ciel" between '22.5' and '27.5' 
      AND "ciea" between '-5' and '0'
      AND "cieb" between '-22.3' and '-17.3' 
    group by "palette_id"
    ) as "palettes"
  left join "palette_color"
```

This also doesn't make much sense.

```
  left join "palette_color" 
    on "palette_color"."palette_id" = "palettes"."palette_id"
```

You already know that palette_color.palette_id is a super set that contains everything that your sub-select contains. So just inner join it.

```
INNER JOIN palette_color USING (palette_id)
```

Other points

- quoting lowercase identifiers in pg is against the social norm. nothing wrong with that, but we don't do it. it adds noise.
- while there is nothing wrong with it, it's really *awkward* to have two tables share the same sequence.

In a query resultset, anything that says `Seq Scan` is the first candidate for a speed up. You need to look at indexing. You have an aggregate over a `DISTINCT` that excludes only two columns `palette_id` and `raw_weight`. Do you ever have two rows in table with different `palette_ids` and `raw_weight`.

I would

- create an index on (ciel, ciea, cieb, weight, hex);
- kill `palette_color.id` You're not using it anywhere, and it seems you can always get it by joining `palette_color` to `palette` through `palette_color.palette_id` and reading `palette.id`. As dezso said in a comment, *are there really palette_color rows where palette_id is NULL?"* seems unlikely to me too.
- make `palette_color.palette_id` the pkey (if you don't kill `palette_color.id` and make `palette_color.palette_id` the pkey, you need to put an index on this or put at the *front* of the list above).

Comment: **Thank you!** I was able to reduce the query from 1 second to 400 miliseconds. Any other ideas?

Edited my original post with the new query!

I dont think I can make palette_color.palette_id a pkey because palette and palette_color have a one to many relationship. For example, 5 palette_colors per palette.

Comment: Do you ever have two rows in table with different palette_ids and raw_weight? Yes I do!

The output I need is per row to have 5ish or so colors with a defined CIEA, CIEB, CIEL, weight, and hex.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE INDEX MyIndex ON public.palette_color (ciel, ciea, cieb, palette_id);
```

Note, that you should put whichever column is likely to narrow the search best first. I assume that your three columns are equally selective so just picked one. The other columns are included so that it can be an index-only read.